# Alternative to Seagate Exos 2X18 ST16000NM0092?

Tags: hard-disk, desktop, sata

I have ordered a Seagate Exos 2X18 [ST16000NM0092](https://www.seagate.com/content/dam/seagate/migrated-assets/www-content/datasheets/pdfs/exos-2x18-DS2093-1-2202US-en_US.pdf), mainly because of its speed specs.

Unfortunately the delivery is delayed and seems also other distributors have the same problem with these "2X" disks.

Can one recommend another hard disk offering similar performance?

It seems the for the "old" Exos, others are similar, but the "2X" is really without alternative.